# Trying to retrieve data from an array depending on user input, JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a random lord generator for a tabletop strategy game I play with my friends, Basically the user chooses what faction to create it for (this then changes the available names) and chooses whether it's a king or a lord (changes the title depending on faction currently selected and rank).

The script will also randomly generate loyalty, wealth and influence (stats needed in the game.) Currently what happens is it displays the stats, and sometimes screws up the influence saying NaN instead of the intended random number, it also shows Undefined Undefined of Undefined instead of CurTitle CurLordName of CurNation.
I ran it through JSlint and only got things telling me it should be at column 5 instead of column 9 etc. so I'm stumped.

```
    // King/Lord creator
// when starting a campaign all kings are NPCs, also some lords are npcs.
//Global Variables
var iFaction, isKing;// faction in numbers (used for calculations)i and is character lord or king? 1 = king 2=lord
var curLordname, curTitle, curNation;  //Current lord name (For output), Current title (For output) and Current nation (For output)
var iModder; // Number to add to the random math
var curWealth; // Lord wealth (random number 200 - 1000)
var curLoyalty; //Lord Loyalty (random number between 1-10)
var curInfluence; //Lord Influence ((random number 1-10 + wealth/100)/2)
// King Titles

var aTitles = new Array();
aTitles[1] = "King";
aTitles[2] = "High Chief";
aTitles[3] = "Anax";
aTitles[4] = "Emperor";
// Lord Titles
aTitles[5] = "Baron";
aTitles[6] = "Jarl";
aTitles[7] = "Stratigos";
aTitles[8] = "Warlord";

// Lords names, Leontrois (1-25), Saxathia(26-50), Hellios(51-75), Drakon(75-100)
var aNames = new Array();
aNames[0] = "Maverick";
//Leontrois Names (Math.floor((Math.random()*25)+1);)
aNames[1] = "Henry";
aNames[2] = "Edward";
aNames[3] = "Thomas";
aNames[4] = "George";
aNames[5] = "Stephen";
aNames[6] = "William";
aNames[7] = "James";
aNames[8] = "Louis";
aNames[9] = "Charles";
aNames[10] = "David";
aNames[11] = "Oliver";
aNames[12] = "Duncan";
aNames[13] = "Leonardo";
aNames[14] = "Phillip";
aNames[15] = "Francis";
aNames[16] = "Johnathan";
aNames[17] = "Richard";
aNames[18] = "Robert";
aNames[19] = "Jacob";
aNames[20] = "Peter";
aNames[21] = "Patrick";
aNames[22] = "Arthur";
aNames[23] = "Isaac";
aNames[24] = "Laurence";
aNames[25] = "Edmund";
// Saxathia Names (Math.floor((Math.random()*25)+26);)
aNames[26] = "Mordra";
aNames[27] = "Horsa";
aNames[28] = "Offa";
aNames[29] = "Sigfryd";
aNames[30] = "Coelwulf";
aNames[31] = "Sledda";
aNames[32] = "Harold";
aNames[33] = "Ulfryk";
aNames[34] = "Ongar";
aNames[35] = "Ragnar";
aNames[36] = "Kren";
aNames[37] = "Merkar";
aNames[38] = "Canute";
aNames[39] = "Kealin";
aNames[40] = "Echbert";
aNames[41] = "Aethelred";
aNames[42] = "Ulfred";
aNames[43] = "Bryn";
aNames[44] = "Godwin";
aNames[45] = "Cin";
aNames[46] = "Oswine";
aNames[47] = "Mul";
aNames[48] = "Cnut";
aNames[49] = "Aelthor";
aNames[50] = "Gryff";
//Hellios Names (Math.floor((Math.random()*25)+51);)
aNames[51] = "Alexander";
aNames[52] = "Ajax";
aNames[53] = "Telemachus";
aNames[54] = "Odysseus";
aNames[55] = "Antinous";
aNames[56] = "Marcus";
aNames[57] = "Julius";
aNames[58] = "Nero";
aNames[59] = "Constantine";
aNames[60] = "Achillies";
aNames[62] = "Agamemnon";
aNames[63] = "Menelaus";
aNames[64] = "Nestor";
aNames[65] = "Laertes";
aNames[66] = "Priam";
aNames[67] = "Hector";
aNames[68] = "Paris";
aNames[69] = "Diomedes";
aNames[70] = "Patroclus";
aNames[71] = "Glaucus";
aNames[72] = "Sarpedon";
aNames[73] = "Idomeneus";
aNames[74] = "Eurymachus";
aNames[75] = "Amphinomus";
//Drakon names (Math.floor((Math.random()*25)+76);)
aNames[76] = "Xiahou";
aNames[77] = "Cao Yi";
aNames[78] = "Sun Li";
aNames[79] = "Ma Tao";
aNames[80] = "Jin Yuan";
aNames[81] = "Huang";
aNames[82] = "Zhong";
aNames[83] = "Fei Song";
aNames[84] = "Chan Yin";
aNames[85] = "Dong Xa";
aNames[86] = "Pang Shao";
aNames[87] = "Keiji";
aNames[88] = "Reiji";
aNames[89] = "Matsuhide";
aNames[90] = "Samonuske";
aNames[91] = "Nobunaga";
aNames[92] = "Ieyasu";
aNames[93] = "Minghuan";
aNames[94] = "Yisun";
aNames[95] = "Erdene";
aNames[96] = "Tolui";
aNames[97] = "Kenji";
aNames[98] = "Masamune";
aNames[99] = "Hassan";
aNames[100] = "Al'Tar";
//End of lord names

// First what nation are you from:
$("#selNation").change(function() {
iFaction = $(this).val();
    switch (iFaction) {
    case 1:
        curNation = "Leontrois";
        iModder = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        //iFaction=2;
        curNation = "Saxathia";
        iModder = 26;
        break;
    case 3:
        //iFaction=3;
        curNation = "Hellios";
        iModder = 51;
        break;
    case 4:
        //iFaction = 4;
        curNation = "Drakon";
        iModder = 76;
        break;
    }
//$("#selLord").disabled = false;
});

$("#selLord").change(function() {
    isKing = $(this).val();
    switch (isKing) {
    case 1:
        curTitle = aTitles[iFaction];
        //  switch(iFaction){
                // case 1:
                // curTitle = aTitles[1];
                // break;
                // case 2:
                // curTitle = aTitles[2];
                // break;
                // case 3:
                // curTitle = aTitles[3];
                // break;
                // case 4:
                // curTitle = aTitles[4];
                // break;
            //}
        break;
    case 2:
        var temp = iFaction + 4;
        curTitle = aTitles[temp];
            // switch(iFaction){
                // case 1:
                // curTitle = aTitles[5];
                // break;
                // case 2:
                // curTitle = aTitles[6];
                // break;
                // case 3:
                // curTitle = aTitles[7];
                // break;
                // case 4:
                // curTitle = aTitles[8];
                // break;
            // }
        break;
    }
//$("#lordbtn").disabled = false;
});

function createlord() {
//get lord name
    var temp2 = Math.floor(curWealth/100) + 1, temp3 = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 10) + temp2) / 2), temp4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + iModder);
    curInfluence = temp3;
    curLoyalty = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    curWealth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 200);
    curLordname = aNames[temp4];
//display result
    var supastring = "<h3>" + curTitle + " " + curLordname + " of " + curNation + ". </h3>" + "<br /> <p>His wealth is " + curWealth + "Gp, His influence is " + curInfluence + " and his loyalty is " + curLoyalty + ".</p>" + "<br /> <button class='btn btn-large' type='button' onclick='resetlord()'>Create another Lord</button>";
//$("#lordresult").innerHTML = supastring;
    document.getElementById("lordresult").innerHTML = supastring;
}
function resetlord() {
// $("#lordresult").innerHTML
//document.getElementById("lordresult").innerHTML 

        document.getElementById("lordresult").innerHTML = "<h2>Broken History: Lord Creator tool</h2>   <small>This tool is designed to help you when playing Broken History 1.0 the CWDC Expansion, and is used to determine the name of a new NPC lords (on the death of a previous lord). Note: 'You' refers to the character being created.</small><br />   <p>Choose faction and rank then click button to generate the new NPC.<br /></p><label>What faction are you from?</label><select id='selNation'><option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Select faction:</option><option value='Leontrois' >Leontrois</option><option value='Saxathia'>Saxathia</option>        <option value='Hellios'>Hellios</option><option value='Drakon'> Drakon</option>      </select><label>Are you the Monarch of a faction?</label><select id='selLord'> <option selected='selected'>Choose rank:</option><option value='1' >Monarch</option><option value='2'>Vassal</option> </select> <button class='btn btn-large' type='button' id='lordbtn' onclick='createlord()'>Generate new lord</button></p>";
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the resulting screen:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: you wouldn't by chance have a jsfiddle of this?

Comment: Here Zero: http://jsfiddle.net/CYe8J/ But I don't think it works properly on there, doesn't seem to work as well as on my test web page :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your event handling codes inside document ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selNation").change(function() {
      ....
    });

    $("#selLord").change(function() {
      .....
    });
});
```

and `iFaction = $(this).val();` but you are comparing it to a number, you should type cast it to be a Number:

```
iFaction = Number($(this).val()); // parseInt also will work
```

lastly, you are using curWealth while its undefined. Defined the value first before using it:

Change this part:

```
var temp2 = Math.floor(curWealth/100) + 1, temp3 = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 10) + temp2) / 2), temp4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + iModder);
    curInfluence = temp3;
    curLoyalty = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    curWealth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 200);
```

to this:

```
curWealth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 200);

var temp2 = Math.floor(curWealth/100) + 1, temp3 = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 10) + temp2) / 2), temp4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + iModder);
    curInfluence = temp3;
    curLoyalty = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

Here's the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYe8J/2/)

Comment: Awesome, but the title selection still doesn't work, now it just says 'King' when it should change depending on Rank/Faction

Comment: and it's only taking names/titles from ifaction=1 not any others :/

Comment: Something I thought about, is the fact that all things in `$(document).ready()` will only be executed when the DOM ready trigger happens right? does this mean that once executed it can't be done again? if so perhaps I could call the functions in the document.ready rather than write them there using some method?

Comment: Is it then possible to simply right the functions e.g. `$("#selNation").change(upNation());` what do you think?

Comment: Yes, `$(document).ready()` will execute right after the DOM is ready, but you can always call it even if the DOM ready has already triggered. In fact, you can have multiple `$(document).ready()` in your code.

Comment: If you do so, remove the parentheses, `$("#selNation").change(upNation);`, just pass the function name.

Comment: Figured out a way around it, Instead of replacing the innerHTML content the reset button just does location.reload(); which re-triggers the Doc.ready, which is coolio, works on jsFiddle, yet to see if it works on the site lols, :)http://jsfiddle.net/CYe8J/26/

Answer (score 1):

selNation change then

```
$("#selNation").change --> set variable "var curNation, iModder, iFaction"
```

selLord change then

```
$("#selLord").change --> set variable "var curTitle"
```

Createlord function

```
function createlord() {


    curLoyalty = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    curWealth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 200);

    // selNation change set 
    curNation = "Leontrois";
    iModder = 1;
    iFaction = 1;

    // selLord change
    curTitle = aTitles[iFaction];




    var temp2 = Math.floor(curWealth/100) + 1, 
        temp3 = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 10) + temp2) / 2), 
        temp4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + iModder);



    curInfluence = temp3;
    curLordname = aNames[temp4];

    var supastring = curTitle + " " + curLordname + " of " + curNation + curWealth + curInfluence + curLoyalty;

}

createlord();
```

Comment: Not sure you understand the purpose of this script

Answer (score 1):

One error you have is misplaced `iFaction` variable, your following code:

```
switch (isKing) {
    case 1:
        curTitle = aTitles[iFaction];
```

should be like this one:

```
switch (isKing) {
    case 1:
        curTitle = aTitles[isKing];
```

Comment: Not so, The switch is designed to give a different result depending on faction/rank the `switch (isKing) {` does the rank via cases 1(king) and 2(vassal), the content of those switches is like this ifaction = 1 to 4 depending on the faction chosen.

Comment: in the aTitles array there are entries 1 to 8, so if the char is king his title would be equal to the number representing his faction (i.e. 1 = leontrois = King, 2 = Saxathia = High chief), the second case in that particular switch uses this code `var temp = iFaction + 4;
  curTitle = aTitles[temp];` which should in theory work as ifaction +4 = atitles 5-8 (the vassal titles)